# Fetching emails for a specific date in c# using Exchange Web Services

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I am able to fetch emails from a mailbox based on a subject. I am not sure what the format for fetching emails based on the received date?

```
           string message = string.Empty;
            Item item = Item.Bind(exService, messageID, PropertySet.FirstClassProperties);

            if (item is EmailMessage)
            {
                EmailMessage em = (EmailMessage)item;

                string strMsg = string.Empty;
                //strMsg = strMsg + item.Id.ToString();
                //strMsg = strMsg + item.DateTimeReceived;
                strMsg = strMsg + "*********************** New Fiscal Email received on " + item.DateTimeReceived  +" ************************************" + Environment.NewLine;

                if (em.Body.Text.Contains("BRANDON"))
                {
                    strMsg = strMsg + em.Body.Text.ToString();
                }
                strMsg = strMsg + "*********************** End of Email Body ************************************" + Environment.NewLine;
                message = strMsg;

            }
```

Comment: The code you provided above isn't searching by subject. It's retrieving messages by `EntryID`.

Answer (score 20):

I think the way SilverNinja told you is the right way.
You should search the items like this:

```
DateTime searchdate = new DateTime (2012,7,6) //Year, month, day
SearchFilter greaterthanfilter = new SearchFilter.IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo(ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived, searchdate );
SearchFilter lessthanfilter = new SearchFilter.IsLessThan(ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived, searchdate.AddDays(1));
SearchFilter filter = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And, greaterthanfilter, lessthanfilter);
Folder folder = Folder.Bind(this.m_Service, WellKnownFolderName.MsgFolderRoot); //Or the folder you want to search in
FindItemsResults<Item> results = folder.FindItems(filter, new ItemView(1000));
```

"results.Items" will return the first 1000 items which are recivied at the day you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [`SearchFilter` examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633659%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx). You just need a filtering condition on [`ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.itemschema.datetimereceived%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx)

Comment: However, I am not able to get what format I should pass. when I try '5/12/2012' it is not retreiving the data

Comment: [Look here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee693615.aspx), and search for "Date range restriction"

Answer (score -2):

This will work.

```
if (em.DateTimeReceived.Equals(**Date you want to search**))
                {
                    strMsg = strMsg + em.Body.Text.ToString();
                }
```

Comment: This will not query the EWS! It will download all the emails anyway.
It does not answer what was asked in the question.