# using filter to get tasks modified after specific date

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, exchangewebservices

Do you have any experiences with SearchFilter of EWS? I'm trying to get tasks with `last modified time` newer than value of variable `date`. It works with this code really in weird way, I've also tried to change date to UTC time format. Any advice what I'm doing wrong?

```
        //Create the extended property definition.
        ExtendedPropertyDefinition taskLastUpdate = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(DefaultExtendedPropertySet.Task, 0x3008, MapiPropertyType.SystemTime);

        //Create the search filter.
        SearchFilter.IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo filter = new SearchFilter.IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo(taskLastUpdate, date.ToString("s") + "Z");
        //Get the tasks.
        FindItemsResults<Item> tasks = _service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Tasks, filter, new ItemView(100));
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10980069/fetching-emails-for-a-specific-date-in-c-sharp-using-exchange-web-services

Comment: thank you. But, As you see, I've tried same way, but doesn't work for me, and I do not know why.

Comment: I don't know, why you convert your date to string. In the example above there is `DateTime`.

Comment: It was cause of SystemTime type, somewhere on MS blogs I've found this - "simple conversion to SystemTime is throw string" it's not problem here. I've found something about errors while using ExtendedProperties. So I try your advice, it finally works, thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why it didn't work way with `ExtendedPropertyDefinition`.

Solution:

```
SearchFilter greaterthanfilter = new SearchFilter.IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo(ItemSchema.LastModifiedTime, date );
SearchFilter filter = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And, greaterthanfilter);
Folder folder = Folder.Bind(_service, WellKnownFolderName.Tasks); //Or the folder you want to search in
FindItemsResults<Item> results = folder.FindItems(filter, new ItemView(1000));
```

Comment: I found this a useful example, but why do you use "SearchFilterCollection" to AND together a single item?  It appears to still work even if you use the "greaterthanfilter" directly.